# Modularizar Conexãoo NodeJs com PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou com problema ao criar um módulo no `nodejs` para exportar minha conexão com o `PostgreSQL`.

Não consegui entender porque o **segundo** código não funciona, pois gostaria de exportar já o `connect`.

**Código 1** .

```
var pg = require('pg');

module.exports = function () {
    var conString = 'postgres://usuario:senha@localhost:5432/teste';
    var conexao = new pg.Client(conString);
    return conexao;
};
```

Chamo dessa forma em meu app:

```
var db = require('../../config/conexao');
var conexao = db();
conexao.connect();
conexao.query('select * from cliente', function (error, result) {..
```

**Código 2**

```
var pg = require('pg');

module.exports = function () {
    var conString = 'postgres://usuario:senha@localhost:5432/teste';
    var conexao = new pg.Client(conString);

    // retorna já a conexao feita 
    return conexao.connect();
};
```

E chamo dessa forma:

```
var conexao = db();
```

> Sem utilizar o `connect`, assim recebo o erro que o método `query` não
>   existe.

*Porque da segunda forma, não consigo encontrar o método `query` em minha conexão?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No segundo código você já está exportando o objeto que representa a conexão. Não é necessário invocá-lo como se fosse uma função.

Portanto, ao invés de importar o módulo dessa forma:

`var conexao = db();`

Você pode simplesmente usar:

`var conexao = db;`

Comment: Certo.  Mas se eu exportar a conexão ja com o conect. Ao dar um require ele já vai estar conectado ao banco ou só qndo atribuiu a uma variável?

Comment: Sim, a conexão ocorre no momento que você chama o método `.connect()`. Quando você exporta o resultado dessa chamada, você está exportando a conexão e poderá reaproveitá-la em outras partes da aplicação (ao invés de conectar ao banco toda vez que precisar realizar uma consulta).

Comment: E essa forma seria a melhor ou não? Pois se já estou conectado com o banco não poderia ser inviável?

Comment: Sim! Sem dúvidas a melhor forma é a segunda. Realizar conexões o tempo todo é uma operação que demanda tempo, sua aplicação pode perder em performance.

Comment: Show obrigado pela informação. Só  outra coisa eu estou exportando uma função no meu módulo.  Pq não posso usar o db () ? Pois pelo que aprendi tenho que chamar assim qndo exportado uma função.